# Custom SF Symbol not rendering hierarchical shading

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have a custom SF Symbol that renders with hierarchical shading when viewed in the SF Symbols 3 app, but in iOS using SwiftUI it renders as monochrome.

Here is the symbol in the SF Symbols 3 app:

[image: custom symbol in SF Symbols 3 app showing layers]

Here is the symbol imported as a 3.0 template in the asset catalog:

[image: symbol in asset catalog]

Here is the code to render it:

```
  Image("custom.figure.steps")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .padding(.trailing)
    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
    .foregroundColor(status.statusColor)
```

Here is how it renders in iOS simulator:

[image: custom symbol as rendered in iOS]

How do I get the hierarchical shading?

Comment: Have your tried rendering it with a standard system color? We can't tell what your `status.statusColor` is.

Comment: Just now tried with `Color(uiColor: .systemRed)` and `Color(uiColor: .systemGray)` and still rendering as monochrome.

Comment: Also, you need to show the layers you set up in SF Symbols.

Comment: @Yrb Edited to include the symbol layers.

Comment: Did you export it as a 3.0 Template to import into Xcode?

Comment: What happens if you use foregroundStyle instead of forwgroundColor?

Comment: I used a 3.0 template and `foregroundStyle(...)` gives same monochrome rendering. FYI, `foregroundColor(...)` renders hierarchically for other symbols, just not the custom symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, discovered my mistake. I exported as a template, which did not preserve the layers. When I exported as a symbol 3.0, the layers were preserved and now things are rendering as expected.

How I diagnosed:

- imported the SVG that I had exported as a template back into SF Symbols and noticed that only a single layer was there
- exported as a symbol and imported that into Xcode, rendered as hierarchical

**Bottom line:** Export as a symbol, not as a template when importing into Xcode.